# Copy formula from a workbook to another

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I want to copy the content of **sheet1** from **workbook1** to **sheet1** in **workbook2**, keeping the formulas intact. Out of these formulas some refer to cells within sheet1, some other to cells in sheet2.

I have tried `copy & paste special/formulas`, but the formulas referencing to workbook1_sheet2 keep refering to workbook1. How can I avoid this?

Comment: If it's just one formula, highlight the formula in the formula bar, copy/paste.  (Don't just copy/paste the cell).  That should keep it, as you're copying the literal string that makes up the formula.

Comment: it's more than one formula, therefore individual copy/paste is too cumbersome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use Search and Replace (Ctrl+H) with "[Workbook1.xlsx]" in the "search for" (without the quotation marks) field and an empty "replace by" field. Click "Replace All" and the reference to the old file should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying and pasting the formulas just assign them directly.  Something like this:

```
Workbooks("test2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = Workbooks("test1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula
```

Comment: This is also an option if I manage to write a macro that opens the files, create the new worksheet and paste the formulas in a shorter time than that I'd need to make the actions manually